# Spring Boot - Tomcat JNDI fails in Service beans

Tags: java, spring, tomcat, jndi

I'm trying to switch datasource from c3p0 to Tomcat JNDI in a Spring Boot 1.1.6 web project. I've found a sample application in [GitHub](https://github.com/wilkinsona/spring-boot-sample-tomcat-jndi), which works fine when DataSource instance is accessed from `@RestController` annotated class.

```
@RestController
public class TestController {

  @Autowired
  private DataSource dataSource;

  @RequestMapping("/test")
  @ResponseBody
  public String test() {

  // Gets object instance... everything is OK...
  System.out.println(this.dataSource); 
  }
```

However, when I try to inject same datasource to `@Service` annotated bean, I get `javax.naming.NameNotFoundException` as soon as instance is used in code.

```
@Service
public class TestService {

  @Autowired
  private DataSource dataSource;

  @PostConstruct
  private void init() {

    // Throws exception...
    System.out.println(this.dataSource);

}
```

Stack trace:

```
Caused by: javax.naming.NameNotFoundException: Name [java:comp/env/jdbc/myDataSource] is not bound in this Context. Unable to find [java:comp].
    at org.apache.naming.NamingContext.lookup(NamingContext.java:819)
    at org.apache.naming.NamingContext.lookup(NamingContext.java:167)
    at javax.naming.InitialContext.lookup(InitialContext.java:411)
    at org.springframework.jndi.JndiTemplate$1.doInContext(JndiTemplate.java:155)
    at org.springframework.jndi.JndiTemplate.execute(JndiTemplate.java:87)
    at org.springframework.jndi.JndiTemplate.lookup(JndiTemplate.java:152)
    at org.springframework.jndi.JndiTemplate.lookup(JndiTemplate.java:179)
    at org.springframework.jndi.JndiLocatorSupport.lookup(JndiLocatorSupport.java:95)
    at org.springframework.jndi.JndiObjectLocator.lookup(JndiObjectLocator.java:106)
    at org.springframework.jndi.JndiObjectTargetSource.getTarget(JndiObjectTargetSource.java:135)
    ... 11 more
```

I wonder why JNDI datasource bean can not be accessed from @Service class ? Any ideas ?

Comment: How did you specify that the container picks up the @Service annotation?

Comment: It's intansiated once when app context boots.

Comment: Are you sure the DI container picks it up? Are you using component-scan?

Comment: Yes, main class is annotated with `@ComponentScan`.

Comment: How are you configuring the jndi template and the datasource beans ?

Comment: You can check the example project linked in question. Datasource bean is structured just like there.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The actual issue is that you are trying to get the datasource within `PostConstruct`, and not that it fails specifically in service beans.

By default, Tomcat uses the thread context class loader to determine which JNDI context a lookup should be performed against. So when you're binding the resource into the web app's JNDI context, you need to ensure that the lookup is performed when the web app's class loader (i.e. `org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.tomcat.TomcatEmbeddedWebappClassLoader`) is the thread context class loader.

Following is the snippet of code for `org.apache.naming.ContextBindings.getClassLoader` which performs the check mentioned above:

```
/**
 * Retrieves the naming context bound to a class loader.
 */
public static Context getClassLoader()
    throws NamingException {
    ClassLoader cl = Thread.currentThread().getContextClassLoader();
    Context context = null;
    do {
        context = clBindings.get(cl);
        if (context != null) {
            return context;
        }
    } while ((cl = cl.getParent()) != null);
    throw new NamingException
        (sm.getString("contextBindings.noContextBoundToCL"));
}
```

So, when the code is within `PostConstruct` and you perform the JNDI lookup (which is done implicitly when you access the object) the thread context class loader is still the application class loader (i.e. `sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader`). This is the reason why JNDI is not able to find the object since it is trying to find `java:comp/env/jdbc/myDataSource` naming context (i.e. `javax.naming.Context`) from `sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader`.

You can move code from `PostConstruct` and it should work perfectly fine.

Crosslinking another [related](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24941829/how-to-create-jndi-context-in-spring-boot-with-embedded-tomcat-container) question, which also provides more insight in the issue.

I hope this answers your question.

Comment: Came here with a somewhat different problem, but this answer gave me exactly the cause of mine. There was no WebappClassLoader in my custom context class loader's hierarchy, so no jndi objects could be found. Thank you.