# Howto use JNDI database connection with Spring Boot and Spring Data using embedded Tomcat?

Tags: spring-boot, embedded-tomcat-8

When I try to use a JNDI datasource with Spring Boot and Spring Data JPA using an embedded Tomcat server, I get the following error message when running the application with SpringApplication.run:

```
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'entityManagerFactory' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/orm/jpa/HibernateJpaAutoConfiguration.class]: Instantiation of bean failed; 
nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanDefinitionStoreException: Factory method [public org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.orm.jpa.JpaBaseConfiguration.entityManagerFactory(org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.orm.jpa.EntityManagerFactoryBuilder)] threw exception;
nested exception is org.springframework.jndi.JndiLookupFailureException: JndiObjectTargetSource failed to obtain new target object; 
nested exception is javax.naming.NameNotFoundException: Name [comp/env/jdbc/myDataSource] is not bound in this Context. Unable to find [comp].
```

I use the configuration described in the solution of [How to create JNDI context in Spring Boot with Embedded Tomcat Container](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24941829/how-to-create-jndi-context-in-spring-boot-with-embedded-tomcat-container)

The only difference is the additional Maven dependency to org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-data-jpa

Here is a sample project: https://github.com/derkoe/spring-boot-sample-tomcat-jndi (this is a modified version of the sample in the solution). Just check out, build and run SampleTomcatJndiApplication.

It seems that the JNDI context used in looking up the database connection is not yet the one from the webapp. This seems to be an ordering problem in the initialization of the Spring context and the Tomcat server.

Any ideas how to solve that?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Tomcat uses the thread's context class loader to determine the JNDI context to perform the lookup against. If the thread context class loader isn't the web app classloader then the JNDI context is empty, hence the lookup failure.

The problem is that the JNDI lookup of the `DataSource` that's performed during startup is being performed on the main thread and the main thread's TCCL isn't Tomcat's web app classloader. You can work around this by updating your `TomcatEmbeddedServletContainerFactory` bean to set the thread context class loader. I've yet to convince myself that this isn't a horrible hack, but it works…

Here's the updated bean:

```java
@Bean
public TomcatEmbeddedServletContainerFactory tomcatFactory() {
    return new TomcatEmbeddedServletContainerFactory() {
        
        @Override
        protected TomcatEmbeddedServletContainer getTomcatEmbeddedServletContainer(
                Tomcat tomcat) {
            tomcat.enableNaming();
            TomcatEmbeddedServletContainer container = 
                    super.getTomcatEmbeddedServletContainer(tomcat);
            for (Container child: container.getTomcat().getHost().findChildren()) {
                if (child instanceof Context) {
                    ClassLoader contextClassLoader = 
                            ((Context)child).getLoader().getClassLoader();
                    Thread.currentThread().setContextClassLoader(contextClassLoader);
                    break;
                }
            }
            return container;
        }

        @Override
        protected void postProcessContext(Context context) {
            ContextResource resource = new ContextResource();
            resource.setName("jdbc/myDataSource");
            resource.setType(DataSource.class.getName());
            resource.setProperty("driverClassName", "your.db.Driver");
            resource.setProperty("url", "jdbc:yourDb");

            context.getNamingResources().addResource(resource);
        }
    };
}
```

`getEmbeddedServletContainer` extracts the context's classloader and set it as the current thread's context class loader. This happens` *after* the call to the super method. This ordering is important as the call to the super method creates and starts the container and, as a part of that creation, creates the context's class loader.

Comment: This is definitively a hack - but it works! Any better idea from the Spring Boot team?

Comment: There is even a "simpler" hack: you can get the context from the container: `container.getTomcat().getHost().findChild("");` No storing in an instance variable necessary.

Comment: I'm a member of the Boot team

Comment: I've opened [an issue](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/issues/2308) to discuss whether or not we should set the TCCL for you.

Comment: The workaround/hack was incorporated into Spring Boot 1.4.

Comment: I'm using Boot 1.4.1 and I still had to add this hack.

Comment: @dustin.schultz Where was this incorporated ? Thanks!

Comment: Thank you soo much!

Answer (score 1):

Based on the GREAT answer of @Andy Wilkinson, I updated the solution for SpringBoot 2.5.3:

```java
public TomcatServletWebServerFactory tomcatFactory() {
    return new TomcatServletWebServerFactory() {
        @Override
        protected TomcatWebServer getTomcatWebServer(org.apache.catalina.startup.Tomcat tomcat) {
            tomcat.enableNaming();
            TomcatWebServer tomcatWebServer = super.getTomcatWebServer(tomcat);
            Container context = tomcatWebServer.getTomcat().getHost().findChild(getContextPath());
            ClassUtils.overrideThreadContextClassLoader(((Context) context).getLoader().getClassLoader());
            return tomcatWebServer;
        }

        @Override
        protected void postProcessContext(Context context) {
             // ...
        }
    };
}
```