# Is it possible to @Lazy init a Spring @Value?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

**Is it possible to `@Lazy` init a Spring `@Value`?**

e.g.

```
@Lazy
@Value("${someConfig}")
private String someConfig;
```

The scenario I'm specifically referring to, is a variable which is set via JNDI, and [an embedded Tomcat container, which has some of it's JNDI variables initialised during Spring Boot loading](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28131577/spring-boot-using-embedded-tomcat-with-jndi)... other scenarios I could think of where you'd want JIT variable population: It's "expensive" to retrieve a variable and you don't want to impact startup time, the variable isn't available at application startup, etc.

The above code gives the following error:

> java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Cannot subclass final class
>   java.lang.String

I imagine you could possibly achieve lazy-loaded variables by using a [`@ConfigurationProperties` bean](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/boot-features-external-config.html#boot-features-external-config-typesafe-configuration-properties)?

A follow up question: **Can/Would a `@Value`-initialised variable be reinitialised (without an app restart), if the underlying variable source is changed (e.g. JNDI on the server)?** i.e. re-retrieved

(I'm in the process of trying these last two scenarios)

Comment: No, to your follow up question, not for a field in a singleton bean. But if you managed to declare the bean as singleton and get a new instance each time, that field would get initialized to the current value each time.

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis Thanks!

Comment: As a note on the specific error: `@Lazy` is implemented by replacing the field with a proxy, which can't be done if the field's declared type is a final class.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can give a try to such a setup. Downside is that it requires beans using this variable to be also declared as `@Lazy`.

```
@Bean(name = "myVar")
@Lazy
String foo(@Value("${someConfig}") String someConfig) {
    return someConfig;
}

@Component
@Lazy
class SomeComponent {

    @Autowired
    @Qualifier("myVar")
    String myVar;
}
```