# Get properties (@Value) in a @Lazy nested component in Spring

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

I have two @Lazy components, one initialized by the second.

Whenever I try to use `@Value({"app.my.prop"})` over some variable nothing happens, the variable is empty.

If I have something like this:

```
@Lazy
@Repository
public class justAClassThatPerhapsCompiles{
    @Value("${app.my.prop}")
    String myProp; 

    @Lazy
    @Autowired
    Environment env;

    void justAFuncThatSomebodyWillTryToCompileMaybe(){
        env.getProperty("app.my.prop"); //env is null
        System.out.println(myProp); //myProp is null
    }
}
```

Again nothing happens, env is null at runtime.

How can I get properties inside the lazily initialized components?

Comment: `@Value{"app.my.prop"})` will never compile, please post the actual code

Comment: is `justAClassThatPerhapsCompiles` a Spring component?

Comment: @AndrewTobilko yes it is

Comment: `@Value` takes one `String` and that `String` should be a SpEL expression, try `@Value("${app.my.prop}")`

Comment: Yes a typo in the question, but that is not the problem.

Comment: can you inject the `Environment` somewhere eagerly?

Comment: Does if work if you use constructor injection for `myProp` and `env`?

Comment: Have a look at this answer as a workaround: [Is it possible to @Lazy init a Spring @Value?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40476761/11133168)

Comment: @AndrewTobilko Actually I'm able to inject Environment inside my first Lazy component, but not inside the nested one.

Comment: @RoddyoftheFrozenPeas Yes, both work. Please post the answer as a workaround.

Comment: @FlorianDe If I declare and initialize the bean in the first component, the second component can see it. If I do it in the second, it does not work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One option would be to use [Constructor Injection](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/using-boot-spring-beans-and-dependency-injection.html) to pass the values of Environment and the property to your class.

```
@Lazy
@Repository
public class JustAClassThatPerhapsCompiles {

    private final String myProp; 
    private final Environment env;

    public JustAClassThatPerhapsCompiles(Environment env, 
                                         @Value("${app.my.prop}") String myProp) {
      this.env = env;
      this.myProp = myProp;
    }

    void justAFuncThatSomebodyWillTryToCompileMaybe(){
        env.getProperty("app.my.prop"); //env should no longer be null
        System.out.println(myProp); //myProp should no longer be null
    }
}
```

Since Spring is still managing the life cycle of the object, Constructor Injection will allow it to pass the reference (env) and the property as it would in a regular object when it lazily initializes your bean.