# Combining Tomcat and Embedded Tomcat JNDI Configs for Grails 3

Tags: tomcat, grails, config, jndi

I'm attempting to combine a JNDI configuration in my Grails 3 application that utilises the embedded Tomcat servlet container as well as the standalone tomcat container (set up by our systems team).

I have used [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35465278/adding-jndi-to-embedded-tomcat-server-in-grails-3) to get my JNDI config working with the Embedded Tomcat container (for localhost development, e.g. grails run-app).

When I run my app on a Tomcat standalone server (after building a war file), with JNDI config in the Tomcat server, I get the following error:

```
SEVERE: ContainerBase.addChild: start:
org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to start component [StandardEngine[Catalina].StandardHost[localhost].StandardContext[/acses]]
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:154)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChildInternal(ContainerBase.java:901)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChild(ContainerBase.java:877)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.addChild(StandardHost.java:632)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDescriptor(HostConfig.java:672)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig$DeployDescriptor.run(HostConfig.java:1862)
        at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'tomcatFactory' defined in acses.Application: Post-processing failed of bean type [class acses.Application$1] failed; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalStateException: Failed to introspect bean class [acses.Application$1] for persistence metadata: could not find class that it depends on
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.applyMergedBeanDefinitionPostProcessors(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:940)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:518)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:482)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:306)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:230)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:302)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:197)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:772)
        at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:839)
        at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:538)
        at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.refresh(EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.java:118)
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:766)
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.createAndRefreshContext(SpringApplication.java:361)
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:307)
        at grails.boot.GrailsApp.run(GrailsApp.groovy:55)
        at org.springframework.boot.context.web.SpringBootServletInitializer.run(SpringBootServletInitializer.java:149)
        at org.grails.boot.context.web.GrailsAppServletInitializer.createRootApplicationContext(GrailsAppServletInitializer.groovy:57)
        at org.springframework.boot.context.web.SpringBootServletInitializer.onStartup(SpringBootServletInitializer.java:85)
        at org.springframework.web.SpringServletContainerInitializer.onStartup(SpringServletContainerInitializer.java:175)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5456)
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
        ... 10 more
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Failed to introspect bean class [acses.Application$1] for persistence metadata: could not find class that it depends on
        at org.springframework.orm.jpa.support.PersistenceAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.findPersistenceMetadata(PersistenceAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:396)
        at org.springframework.orm.jpa.support.PersistenceAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessMergedBeanDefinition(PersistenceAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:333)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.applyMergedBeanDefinitionPostProcessors(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:935)
        ... 30 more
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/tomcat/util/descriptor/web/ContextResource
        at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredMethods0(Native Method)
        at java.lang.Class.privateGetDeclaredMethods(Class.java:2701)
        at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredMethods(Class.java:1975)
        at org.springframework.util.ReflectionUtils.getDeclaredMethods(ReflectionUtils.java:609)
        at org.springframework.util.ReflectionUtils.doWithLocalMethods(ReflectionUtils.java:486)
        at org.springframework.orm.jpa.support.PersistenceAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.buildPersistenceMetadata(PersistenceAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:426)
        at org.springframework.orm.jpa.support.PersistenceAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.findPersistenceMetadata(PersistenceAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:392)
        ... 32 more
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.tomcat.util.descriptor.web.ContextResource
        at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1720)
        at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1571)
        ... 39 more
```

To get it working, I need to comment out the `tomcatFactory()` method in the Application.groovy file

My build.gradle file has the following dependency as per the linked SO question:

```
runtime "org.apache.tomcat:tomcat-dbcp:9.0.0.M1"
```

Does anyone know how I might be able to combine the two configurations so that I do not have to comment out the Embedded Tomcat Container when I test locally?

**Update**: The Tomcat version on our servers is `tomcat-7.0.54-2.el7_1.noarch`. I have read various blogs and pages suggesting that going from embedded server to Tomcat container should be a minimum of 7.0.55. Could this be a version inadequacy issue?

Answer (score 0):

Basing on [docs](http://docs.grails.org/3.0.17/guide/deployment.html):

> Note that by default Grails will include an embeddable version of
>   Tomcat inside the WAR file so that it is runnable (see the previous
>   section), this can cause problems if you deploy to a different version
>   of Tomcat. If you don't intend to use the embedded container then you
>   should change the scope of the Tomcat dependencies to provided prior
>   to deploying to your production container in build.gradle:

change:

`runtime "org.apache.tomcat:tomcat-dbcp:9.0.0.M1"`

to

`provided "org.apache.tomcat:tomcat-dbcp:9.0.0.M1"`

Comment: This has no effect. I still get the same error on start up. I'm starting to wonder if it has something to do with the tomcat versions.