# Spring boot configure tomcat context.xml datasource

Tags: tomcat, spring-boot, datasource

I create one context.xml and put in /src/main/resources with my datasource:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <Context cookies="true">
        <Resource name="BeanManager"
            auth="Container"
            type="javax.enterprise.inject.spi.BeanManager"
            factory="org.jboss.weld.resources.ManagerObjectFactory" />

  <Resource
    name="jdbc/PortalServicos"
    auth="Container"
    type="javax.sql.DataSource"
    driverClassName="org.postgresql.Driver"
    url="jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/portalservicos"
    username="user"
    password="pass"
    removeAbandoned="true"
    logAbandoned="true" />
</Context>
```

and put in my application.properties

```
spring.datasource.jndi-name=java:/comp/env/jdbc/ConectorPortalServicos
```

but when i try to run i got this error:

> Exception in thread "main"
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error
>   creating bean with name
>   'org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.orm.jpa.HibernateJpaAutoConfiguration':
>   Injection of autowired dependencies failed; nested exception is
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not
>   autowire field: private javax.sql.DataSource
>   org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.orm.jpa.JpaBaseConfiguration.dataSource;
>   nested exception is
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error
>   creating bean with name 'dataSource' defined in class path resource
>   [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/jdbc/JndiDataSourceAutoConfiguration.class]:
>   Bean instantiation via factory method failed; nested exception is
>   org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to
>   instantiate [javax.sql.DataSource]: Factory method 'dataSource' threw
>   exception; nested exception is
>   org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.lookup.DataSourceLookupFailureException:
>   Failed to look up JNDI DataSource with name
>   'java:/comp/env/jdbc/ConectorPortalServicos'; nested exception is
>   javax.naming.NoInitialContextException: Need to specify class name in
>   environment or system property, or as an applet parameter, or in an
>   application resource file:  java.naming.factory.initial   at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessPropertyValues(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:334)
>     at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1210)
>     at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:537)
>     at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:476)
>     at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:303)
>     at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:230)
>     at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:299)
>     at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:194)
>     at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(ConstructorResolver.java:368)
>     at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1119)
>     at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1014)
>     at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:504)
>     at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:476)
>     at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:303)
>     at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:230)
>     at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:299)
>     at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:194)
>     at
>   org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.getBean(AbstractApplicationContext.java:956)
>     at
>   org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:747)
>     at
>   org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:480)
>     at
>   org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.refresh(EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.java:118)
>     at
>   org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:686)
>     at
>   org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:320)
>     at
>   org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:957)
>     at
>   org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:946)
>     at br.com.lumera.Application.main(Application.java:16) Caused by:
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not
>   autowire field: private javax.sql.DataSource
>   org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.orm.jpa.JpaBaseConfiguration.dataSource;
>   nested exception is
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error
>   creating bean with name 'dataSource' defined in class path resource
>   [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/jdbc/JndiDataSourceAutoConfiguration.class]:
>   Bean instantiation via factory method failed; nested exception is
>   org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to
>   instantiate [javax.sql.DataSource]: Factory method 'dataSource' threw
>   exception; nested exception is
>   org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.lookup.DataSourceLookupFailureException:
>   Failed to look up JNDI DataSource with name
>   'java:/comp/env/jdbc/ConectorPortalServicos'; nested exception is
>   javax.naming.NoInitialContextException: Need to specify class name in
>   environment or system property, or as an applet parameter, or in an
>   application resource file:  java.naming.factory.initial   at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:561)
>     at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InjectionMetadata.inject(InjectionMetadata.java:88)
>     at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessPropertyValues(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:331)
>     ... 25 more Caused by:
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error
>   creating bean with name 'dataSource' defined in class path resource
>   [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/jdbc/JndiDataSourceAutoConfiguration.class]:
>   Bean instantiation via factory method failed; nested exception is
>   org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to
>   instantiate [javax.sql.DataSource]: Factory method 'dataSource' threw
>   exception; nested exception is
>   org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.lookup.DataSourceLookupFailureException:
>   Failed to look up JNDI DataSource with name
>   'java:/comp/env/jdbc/ConectorPortalServicos'; nested exception is
>   javax.naming.NoInitialContextException: Need to specify class name in
>   environment or system property, or as an applet parameter, or in an
>   application resource file:  java.naming.factory.initial   at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(ConstructorResolver.java:599)
>     at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1119)
>     at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1014)
>     at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:504)
>     at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:476)
>     at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:303)
>     at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:230)
>     at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:299)
>     at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:194)
>     at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.findAutowireCandidates(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1120)
>     at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doResolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1044)
>     at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:942)
>     at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:533)
>     ... 27 more Caused by:
>   org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to
>   instantiate [javax.sql.DataSource]: Factory method 'dataSource' threw
>   exception; nested exception is
>   org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.lookup.DataSourceLookupFailureException:
>   Failed to look up JNDI DataSource with name
>   'java:/comp/env/jdbc/ConectorPortalServicos'; nested exception is
>   javax.naming.NoInitialContextException: Need to specify class name in
>   environment or system property, or as an applet parameter, or in an
>   application resource file:  java.naming.factory.initial   at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.SimpleInstantiationStrategy.instantiate(SimpleInstantiationStrategy.java:189)
>     at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(ConstructorResolver.java:588)
>     ... 39 more Caused by:
>   org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.lookup.DataSourceLookupFailureException:
>   Failed to look up JNDI DataSource with name
>   'java:/comp/env/jdbc/ConectorPortalServicos'; nested exception is
>   javax.naming.NoInitialContextException: Need to specify class name in
>   environment or system property, or as an applet parameter, or in an
>   application resource file:  java.naming.factory.initial   at
>   org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.lookup.JndiDataSourceLookup.getDataSource(JndiDataSourceLookup.java:48)
>     at
>   org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.jdbc.JndiDataSourceAutoConfiguration.dataSource(JndiDataSourceAutoConfiguration.java:58)
>     at
>   org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.jdbc.JndiDataSourceAutoConfiguration$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$9eb06593.CGLIB$dataSource$0()
>     at
>   org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.jdbc.JndiDataSourceAutoConfiguration$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$9eb06593$$FastClassBySpringCGLIB$$e2fbd35a.invoke()
>     at
>   org.springframework.cglib.proxy.MethodProxy.invokeSuper(MethodProxy.java:228)
>     at
>   org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassEnhancer$BeanMethodInterceptor.intercept(ConfigurationClassEnhancer.java:309)
>     at
>   org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.jdbc.JndiDataSourceAutoConfiguration$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$9eb06593.dataSource()
>     at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)  at
>   sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
>     at
>   sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
>     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)     at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.SimpleInstantiationStrategy.instantiate(SimpleInstantiationStrategy.java:162)
>     ... 40 more Caused by: javax.naming.NoInitialContextException: Need
>   to specify class name in environment or system property, or as an
>   applet parameter, or in an application resource file: 
>   java.naming.factory.initial   at
>   javax.naming.spi.NamingManager.getInitialContext(NamingManager.java:662)
>     at
>   javax.naming.InitialContext.getDefaultInitCtx(InitialContext.java:313)
>     at
>   javax.naming.InitialContext.getURLOrDefaultInitCtx(InitialContext.java:350)
>     at javax.naming.InitialContext.lookup(InitialContext.java:417)  at
>   org.springframework.jndi.JndiTemplate$1.doInContext(JndiTemplate.java:155)
>     at
>   org.springframework.jndi.JndiTemplate.execute(JndiTemplate.java:87)
>     at
>   org.springframework.jndi.JndiTemplate.lookup(JndiTemplate.java:152)
>     at
>   org.springframework.jndi.JndiTemplate.lookup(JndiTemplate.java:179)
>     at
>   org.springframework.jndi.JndiLocatorSupport.lookup(JndiLocatorSupport.java:95)
>     at
>   org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.lookup.JndiDataSourceLookup.getDataSource(JndiDataSourceLookup.java:45)
>     ... 51 more

Comment: [This answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24941829/how-to-create-jndi-context-in-spring-boot-with-embedded-tomcat-container/24944671#24944671) should help. It doesn't use a `context.xml`, but it does show how to get JNDI set up.

Comment: Resource is named "jdbc/PortalServicos" while application.properties contains "jdbc/ConectorPortalServicos"