# How to Configure JNDI DataSource in Tomcat 8 with Java Configuration:

Tags: java, spring, jndi

How to Configure JNDI DataSource in Java Configuration File Instead of Following Code Snippet in "web.xml" Servlet Context:

```
<resource-ref>
   <description>DB Connection</description>
   <res-ref-name>jdbc/DatabaseName</res-ref-name>
   <res-type>javax.sql.DataSource</res-type>
   <res-auth>Container</res-auth>
</resource-ref>
```

Comment: Is answered here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24941829/how-to-create-jndi-context-in-spring-boot-with-embedded-tomcat-container/26005740#26005740

Comment: It was answered here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24941829/how-to-create-jndi-context-in-spring-boot-with-embedded-tomcat-container/26005740#26005740

Answer (score 9):

Note:  Don't Forget to Copy the "mysql-connector-java-5.1.36.jar" Into Tomcat's "lib" Subfolder in Main Installation Folder.

First: Add following Dependency in Your "pom.xml" File:

```
 <dependency>
     <groupId>mysql</groupId>
     <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
     <version>5.1.36</version>
 </dependency>
```

Second: Create META-INF Folder and "context.xml" File in "webapp" Root Folder Like the Following Picture:

[image]

Third: Add the Following Code Snippet in "context.xml" File:

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8'?>

<Context>
    <Resource name="jdbc/DatabaseName" auth="Container" type="javax.sql.DataSource"
              maxActive="50" maxIdle="30" maxWait="10000"
              username="DatabaseUsername" password="DatabasePasssword"
              driverClassName="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver"
              url="jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/DatabaseName"/>
</Context>
```

Fourth: Create the Following Bean in Spring Context Configuration File:

```
@Bean
public DataSource dataSource() {
    JndiDataSourceLookup dataSource = new JndiDataSourceLookup();
    dataSource.setResourceRef(true);
    return dataSource.getDataSource("jdbc/DatabaseName");
}
```

Note: "jdbc/DatabaseName" is "name" Attribute that We Added Already in "context.xml" File.

Answer (score 2):

To complete SMGs answer: for xml-configured Spring, I use the following code (note the "webapp" profile, as for unit-tests you need to have a webserver-independent datasource)

```
<beans profile="webapp">
    <!-- get dataSources from web-container -->
    <bean name="dataSource" class="org.springframework.jndi.JndiObjectFactoryBean" scope="singleton">
        <property name="jndiName" value="java:comp/env/jdbc/DatabaseName" />
        <property name="resourceRef" value="true" />
    </bean>
</beans>
```

Answer (score 0):

It can be done in 3 steps:

**Step 1:**

Add below entry in tomcat conf/server.xml under **GlobalNamingResources** tag.

```
  <Resource auth="Container" driverClassName="DB_Drive_class-name" maxActive="100" maxIdle="30" maxWait="10000" name="jdbc/MyJNDI" password="&&&&&&&&&&&&&" type="javax.sql.DataSource" url="jdbc:db2://URL:PORT/DBNAME" username="&&&&&&&&&"/>
```

**Step 2:**

Add below entry in tomcat conf/context.xml under root **context**  tag.

```
<ResourceLink  name="jdbc/MyJNDI"  global="jdbc/MyJNDI" type="javax.sql.DataSource"/>
```

**Step 3:**

Add DataSource ref in **web.xml**

```
<resource-ref>
 <description>DB2 Datasource</description>
 <res-ref-name>jdbc/MyJNDI</res-ref-name>
 <res-type>javax.sql.DataSource</res-type>
 <res-auth>Container</res-auth>
</resource-ref>
```

**Note:** This is a global Tomcat configuration and DataSource can be shared with different applications.