# SpringBoot 2.2.6 JUnit dataSource lookup error

Tags: postgresql, spring-boot, jpa, junit

I'm working on a big project written with `java8` and `SringBoot 2.2.6`. The project uses `Envers` and, the girl builds the architecture say to me that she doesn't manage to put in the `application.properties` the `Envers` configuration. Than she do as follows:

```
@Configuration
public class JPAConfig {

 @Autowired
 private DataSource dataSource;

 @Bean(name="entityManagerFactory")
 public LocalSessionFactoryBean sessionFactory() throws IOException {
    LocalSessionFactoryBean factoryBean = new LocalSessionFactoryBean();
    factoryBean.setHibernateProperties(getHibernateProperties());
    factoryBean.setDataSource(dataSource);
    factoryBean.setPackagesToScan("it.xxxx.xxxxx.xxxxx.common.model");
    return factoryBean;
 }

 @Bean
 public PersistenceExceptionTranslationPostProcessor exceptionTranslation() {
    return new PersistenceExceptionTranslationPostProcessor();
 }

 private Properties getHibernateProperties() {
    Properties properties = new Properties();
    properties.put("hibernate.dialect", PostgreSQL82Dialect.class.getName());
    properties.put("hibernate.default_schema", "test");
    properties.put("hibernate.listeners.envers.autoRegister", true);
    properties.put("org.hibernate.envers.revision_field_name", "rev");
    properties.put("org.hibernate.envers.revision_type_field_name", "rev_type");
    properties.put("org.hibernate.envers.audit_table_prefix", "aud_");
    properties.put("org.hibernate.envers.store_data_at_delete", true);
    properties.put("org.hibernate.envers.audit_table_suffix", "");
    
    return properties;
 }

}
```

Problem is that without `dataSource class name` I can't start my `@SpringBootTest` classes and I don't know how to add it in a scenario like this (without change the configuration I mean).

I also tries to add this row inside the `application.properties`:

```
spring.profiles.active=@spring.profile@
spring.datasource.driver-class-name=org.postgresql.Driver
#JPA
spring.datasource.jndi-name=jdbc/test
```

But doesn't work at all..

If I run the App with `JUnit` I obtain this error:

```
org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.lookup.DataSourceLookupFailureException: Failed to look up JNDI DataSource with name 'jdbc/test'; nested exception is javax.naming.NoInitialContextException: Need to specify class name in environment or system property, or as an applet parameter, or in an application resource file:  java.naming.factory.initial
```

Can you help me??

Thanks a lot

Comment: The problem is this line spring.datasource.jndi-name=jdbc/test This only works in a Java EE server

Comment: And than?? A quick solution without change the whole configuration?

Comment: You can create you own application.properties under /test/resources just for the tests

Comment: Is not the answer I hope but thanks anyway..

Answer (score 0):

You need to register your `Datasource` as JNDI resource in the `spring-boot` embedded tomcat.

You can add it as test scope configuration.

This answer shows how to register a JNDI resource: https://stackoverflow.com/a/26005740/5230585