# Context initializing tomcat9/jdbc

Tags: java, postgresql, spring-boot, tomcat9

I have defined the resource as following in conf in ***/var/lib/tomcat9/conf/server.xml***

```
<GlobalNamingResources>
   <Resource name="jdbc/myservice" auth="Container" type="javax.sql.DataSource"
          // credentials for db - password and username as well
          driverClassName="org.postgresql.Driver"
          url="jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/myservice"
          maxTotal="25"
          maxIdle="10"
          validationQuery="select 1" /> 
</GlobalNamingResources>
```

and ResourceLink my ***/var/lib/tomcat9/conf/context.xml***:

```
<Context>
   <ResourceLink 
    name="jdbc/myservice" 
    global="jdbc/myservice" 
    type="javax.sql.DataSource"/>
</Context>
```

when I am trying to test the Context:

```
@SpringBootApplication
public class MailServiceApp {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        SpringApplication.run(MailServiceApp.class, args);
        InitialContext cxt = new InitialContext();

        DataSource ds = (DataSource) cxt.lookup( "java:/comp/env/jdbc/myservice" );
    }
}
```

I get the following exception:

```
Exception in thread "main" javax.naming.NoInitialContextException: Need to specify class name in environment or system property, or in an application resource file: java.naming.factory.initial
```

I've also tried, still is not working

```
 DataSource ds = (DataSource) cxt.lookup( "jdbc/myservice" );
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to create JNDI context in Spring Boot with Embedded Tomcat Container](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24941829/how-to-create-jndi-context-in-spring-boot-with-embedded-tomcat-container)

Comment: @PiotrP.Karwasz thank you for the advice, but the configuration I've provided turned out to be correct. I solved the issue with editing tomcat run configuration in my IntelliJ IDEA