# javax.naming.NoInitialContextException: while running JUNIT test cases in webservices

Tags: java, web-services, soap, junit, jndi

I have JNDI config for all possible database connectivity in my application. Meanwhile I am using JUNIT to test my applications. I find successful connection form my webservices class invocation but error throws while calling it through junit test class.

My JNDI setting is

```
public static Connection getConnectionPool() {
    Connection conn = null;
System.out.println("Creating connection pool.");
    try {
        Context initContext = new InitialContext();
        Context envContext  = (Context)initContext.lookup("java:/comp/env");
        DataSource ds = (DataSource)envContext.lookup(getJNDIName());
        conn = ds.getConnection();
    } catch (SQLException e1) {
        e1.printStackTrace();
    } catch (NamingException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return conn;

}

private static String getJNDIName()
{
    if(!readJNDI)
    {
        try{
            Properties prop = new Properties();
            prop.load(Thread.currentThread().getContextClassLoader().getResourceAsStream("config.properties"));
            JNDIName = prop.getProperty("jndi.name");
            System.out.println("JNDIName : "+JNDIName);
            readJNDI = true;
        }catch(Exception ex){
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
    return JNDIName;
}
```

Below mentioned is the  error.

> javax.naming.NoInitialContextException: Need to specify class name in
>   environment or system property, or as an applet parameter, or in an
>   application resource file:  java.naming.factory.initial

How do I resolve it.?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I think its duplicate http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1525385/noinitialcontextexception-errori

Answer (score 1):

You should use a local datasource.

Just pull out the DataSource/TransactionManager definition into a separate XML file, and use that instead of the JNDI one during testing.

You can still use all the rest of your configuration.