# Java program returns "NoInitialContextException - Cannot instantiate class"

Tags: java, jndi

When I run my program in Intellij, it throws this error on a console:

```
javax.naming.NoInitialContextException: Cannot instantiate class: com.sun.enterprise.naming.SerialInitContextFactory [Root exception is java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.sun.enterprise.naming.SerialInitContextFactory]
```

Now, from what I gathered, it's clearly this piece of code that I wrote here that causes this error:

```
Properties props = new Properties();

            props.put("java.naming.factory.initial", "com.sun.enterprise.naming.SerialInitContextFactory");
            props.put("java.naming.factory.url.pkgs", "com.sun.enterprise.naming");
            props.put("java.naming.factory.state", "com.sun.corba.ee.impl.presentation.rmi.JNDIStateFactoryImpl");
```

I am trying to understand more about this issue and how to resolve it.I've looked into this thread for example:

[The meaning of NoInitialContextException error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1525385/the-meaning-of-noinitialcontextexception-error)

Yet I couldn't find any JNDI properties file for me to set this configuration. What should I be looking at in this case?

### Edit

My library import:

```
import java.util.Properties;
import javax.naming.Context;
import javax.naming.InitialContext;
```

Comment: You have set a factory to use for the `InitialContext`, but you also need to provide the jar implementing that factory.. Assuming you are not running your application on the server (glassfish I would guess ? )

Comment: @AxelH How do I set the factory? Where do I find the jar?

Comment: Already looked into that before, doesn't solve my problem

Comment: Perhaps using `setProperty` instead of `put` would solve it

Comment: Can you develop exactly what you have. Is it a standalone or running on the server ?  What library did you add ?

Comment: It's just a standalone application. I edit my post to include the library

Comment: Already spent some days on this issue,still no luck.

Comment: I think what I need to do is find the jar file but I do not know where to get em

Comment: By "library", I mean jar file added to your build path. PS: please don't send 3 comments in a row, edit the previous to add information. This is not a chat room.

Comment: I see. There;s over more than 20, which one should i be looking out for?

Comment: Why do you mark it as duplicate as it doesn't solve my problem?

Comment: The duplicate have answers about how the library to add and how to do it (with maven).